# Help with linq orderby on class aggregate relationships

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I am getting a little confused and need some help please.  Take these two classes

```
public class Comment
{
     public string Message {get; set;}
     public DateTime Created {get; set;}
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId {get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}
    public IList<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

I want to write a linq query which returns a single Post but ordered by the comment created date.

So i started off constructing my linq query as follows:

```
var query = from p in _repository.GetPosts()
                        where p.PostId == id
                        orderby p.Comments.Select(x => x.Created)
                        select p;

            return query.Single();
```

But the orderby statement seem not to work!  It just returns my list in the default sort order.  Any suggestions on how i can make this work???
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordered by *which* comment date? the first? the last? You cuold try:

```
orderby p.Comments.Max(x=>x.Created)
```

for example.

Also - your `Single` suggests you expect **exactly** one row, in which case there isn't much point sorting it. Do you mean `First()` ?

---

Or do you mean that you want to sort the `Comments`? In which case, get the `Post` first;

```
Post post = ...
```

Now... sorting the `Comments` is a little tricky because of your `IList<T>` - if you don't mind it being a little inefficient, this is simple:

```
post.Comments = post.Comments.OrderBy(x=>x.Created).ToList();
```

Of course, if the `Comments` was `List<T>`, you could do:

```
post.Comments.Sort((x, y) => (x.Created.CompareTo(y.Created)));
```

There are also tricks you can do to make an extension method of the form:

```
post.Comments.Sort(x=>x.Created);
```

i.e.

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(
    this List<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    source.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your orderby projection is returning an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` - that sounds unlikely to be what you want.

A post has many comments - which one do you want to take as the one to use the created date of for ordering? My guess is the first:

```
var query = from p in _repository.GetPosts()
                    where p.PostId == id
                    orderby {
                        Comment comment = p.Comments.FirstOrDefault();
                        return comment == null ? DateTime.MinValue : comment.Created;
                    }
                    select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will returns in an IEnumerable collection, which isn't a comparable value:

```
p.Comments.Select(x => x.Created)
```

Try this instead:

```
p.Comments.Max(x => x.Created)
```

Which returns the most recent comment's date

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the resulting list of comments you can do it after fetching the post by doing:

```
p.Comments = p.Comments.OrderBy(x => x.Created).ToList();
```

.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to sort the list of posts by a list of comment created dates, not sort the list of comments.

If I've read your question correctly, I assume you want to get the single post out, then order the comments within that post. Try the following to do that:

```
var query = from p in _repository.GetPosts()
            where p.PostId == id
            orderby p.Comments.Select(x => x.Created)
            select p;

var ret = query.Single();
ret.Comments = ret.Comments.OrderBy(x => x.Created).ToList();
return ret;
```